# Linear layout children not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add image views to a linear layout at runtime.

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llFolderLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".65"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

```java
LinearLayout llFolderTabs = (LinearLayout) myfolder.findViewById(R.id.llFolderLayout);
ImageView imgTab = new ImageView(activity);
imgTab.setId(i);
imgTab.setTag(i);
imgTab.setImageDrawable(
    mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_folder_inactive));
if (i == 0) {
    imgTab.setImageDrawable(
        mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_folder_active));
    // imgTab.setPadding(10, 0, 4, 0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        74, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(15, 0, 0, 0);
    imgTab.setLayoutParams(lp);
} else {
    // imgTab.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        74, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
    imgTab.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
llFolderTabs.addView(imgTab);
```

However, when the number of children exceeds the screen size it doesn't scroll horizontally - how can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ScrollView` for vertical scrolling or `HorizontalScrollView` for horizontal scrolling. A `ScrollView` can only have one root view, so place your LinearLayout in scrollView and add images to linearlayout like how you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. Make `ScrollView` to be the root element in your xml.